# Force case on dictionary to compare user input in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, lowercase

I'm making a user input decision tree and I want to force the dictionary that the input is being compared to into lowercase. I've placed .lower() at various points and keep getting errors.

```
not_found = True
while True:
    if OPTIONS == "1" or 'a':
        ARTIST_PICK = str(raw_input(
            "Please pick an artist\n"
            "Or Q to quit: ")).lower
        print ARTIST_PICK

        **entries = allData(filename).data_to_dict()
        for d in entries:
            arts = d['artist']**

        if ARTIST_PICK in arts:
            print "found it"

        elif ARTIST_PICK == 'q':
            break

        else:
            print "Sorry, that artist could not be found. Choose again."
            not_found = False
```

This is a sample of the "entries" I'm trying to make lower and compare the user input to:

```
[{'album': 'Nikki Nack', 'song': 'Find a New Way', 'datetime': '2014-12-03 09:08:00', 'artist': 'tUnE-yArDs'},]
```

Comment: I see you're doing `)).lower` right now. Remember to actually call the method. Try `)).lower()` instead. Also, `if OPTIONS == '1' or 'a'` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Missing the () after lower was my typo, sorry. But my problem is how to do I make the d['artist'] lower case also so I can check if the user input is a value in d['artist']?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your problem was just comparing the artist names, then you could use list comprehension to make everything lowercase.

```
entries = allData(filename).data_to_dict()

if ARTIST_PICK in [ d['artist'].lower() for d in entries ]:
    print("found it")
elif ARTIST_PICK == "q":
    break
else
    print("Sorry, that artist could not be found. Choose again.")
```

Or if you'd rather use a `for` loop (rearranged a little for readability):

```
if(ARTIST_PICK != 'q'):
    entries = allData(filename).data_to_dict()

    found = False

    for d in entries:
        if ARTIST_PICK == d['artist'].lower():
            found = True
            break
        elif ARTIST_PICK == "q":
            break

    if(found):
        print("found it")
    else:
        print("Sorry, that artist could not be found. Choose again.")
else:
    # handle the case where the input is 'q' here if you want
```

By the way, as a matter of principle you should name your boolean variables as though you were using them in a sentence. Instead of setting a variable `not_found` to `False` if the variable isn't found, set a variable named `found` to `False` or set `not_found` to `True`. Makes things easier in the long run.

Comment: The for loop isn't cycling through all the d['artist'] entries, only producing a 'found it' when the first item is entered. Any help there?

Comment: Right. Instead of a `for` loop, this code creates list of all teh artist names in lowercase (the line with the `if`). I'll add an example with a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

ARTIST_PICK = str(raw_input(
            "Please pick an artist\n"
            "Or Q to quit: ")).lower()